# How to get first row of each status?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I want to get the first row of each status for each id.

There can be multiple rows for each status. So I want to get the first occurrence of each status based on the previous status.

e.g. *info_required* first occurs at row 2, then it changes to another status *pending* at row 4, and then *info_required* again at row 6.
Likewise, status *pending* first at row 4, then at row 8 since the status changed after row4, it needs to be in the resultset.

Hence below I want to get the row number 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8.

[image]

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-19 11:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-19 12:00:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-19 12:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-20 13:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-20 14:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-20 15:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS row, 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-20 16:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at
    )
SELECT *
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and `qualify()`:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify lag(status) over (partition by id order by created_at) is distinct from status;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(status) over (partition by id 
                                                   order by created_at) AS cce
  FROM t1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, cce ORDER BY created_at) = 1;
```

[image]

---

Data preparation:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS 
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 1 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-19 11:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-19 12:00:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-19 12:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-20 13:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-20 14:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'info_required' AS status, '2021-05-20 15:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS row_, 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-20 16:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at
)
SELECT *
FROM t1;
```

Cte part:

```
SELECT *, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(status) over (partition by id 
                                              order by created_at) AS cce
FROM t1;
```

[image]